# Decide which ribbon tab to be selected

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-2010, excel-2013

The program, that I'm working on, has a separate (additional) Add-in tab in the Excel ribbon. And there are our custom controls, etc. Some of the controls open a new workbook (new Excel window).

In Excel 2010, when the new workbook is opened, our custom tab is selected by default. But in 2013, the first (Home) tab is selected.

In the project, there is no code that controls which tab to be selected by default in a newly open workbook. That is why I am wondering it works in 2010, but not in 2013?

I researched about that, but I could find mostly articles about "how to create new tab", etc.

Any ideas and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Excel 2013 opens each workbook in a **new** window, which has its _own_  top level window frame and ribbon which will be initialized using application defaults (like activating the 'Home' tab). Excel 2010 opens a new workbook in the **same** window, with the existing frame and ribbon for which your code has already setup.

Comment: Actually, the application I'm working on, opens each workbook in **new** window even on 2010, and still the custom tab is selected. But thanks for the info! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the fix you're looking for:

```
yourRibbonInstance.ActivateTab("tabID")
```

keep in mind that the `id` of the tab might not be the same as its displayed name.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this might be overkill but you could use a macro that runs on the workbook open event to activate the sheet you want to see first..

`Sub workbook_open()
 Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
 End Sub`

Comment: The sheets are the tabs in the bottom (like different pages of a notebook). I need the one in top, which are in the ribbon - that's the target that I want selected (activated) by default.